# c++ no matching constructor?

Tags: c++, string, class, constructor

I have to create an own string class for a university project, my code so far looks like(I only show the relevant parts):

```
class SuchString
{
    char* str;
    size_t siz;
public:
    SuchString(char* a);
    ~SuchString();
    SuchString(SuchString& a);
    SuchString operator+(const SuchString& a) const;
    ...
    ...
};
```

As you can see I have a constructor for `char*` types, implemented as:

```
SuchString::SuchString(char* a)
{
    siz = strlen(a);
    str = new char[siz];
    strcpy(str, a);
}
```

The problem is with my `operator+` function:

```
SuchString SuchString::operator+(const SuchString &a) const
{
    return SuchString(strcat(str, a.str));
}
```

I get the following error message:

> No matching constructor for initialization of 'SuchString'

As far my understanding goes, the `strcat` function should return with a `char*`, and I have a constructor for that type.

I get the same error message for the following:

```
SuchString SuchString::operator+(const SuchString &a) const
{
    char* lel = strcat(str, a.str);
    return SuchString(lel);
}
```

And again, the same thing happens. I expected that the code `SuchString(lel)` would create a temporary variable, so the function can return with it, just as in the previous example.

Any help is appreciated.

ps: I know it's absolute nonsense to create a string class like this, but this is some small project for university.

Comment: Beware the local variable in the `char*` constructor - your member variable is left uninitialised. Also watch out for the `operator+` that modifies its left-hand argument and overflows the allocation.

Comment: thanks, I don't really know why I did that

Comment: `str = new char[siz];` should be `str = new char[siz+1];` for the null character

Comment: I have a size variable in my class, why would I need a '\0' escape character? Also, when filling the array of characters from the console, this way I don't need to add the '\0' at the end of the input. The only thing I should watch out for is the '\0' in literal strings(const char*), as that is added automatically in that case. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SuchString(SuchString& a);` takes a non-`const` reference as a parameter, so passing it temporaries is not doable. What you probably want is

```
SuchString(const SuchString& a);
```

because when you return by value, a copy is made - i.e.:

```
return SuchString(lel);
```

will create a temporary `SuchString` which is then copied and returned. In theory, that is, because in practice the copy is most likely optimized out.